# How to access state variable in static functions `title` or `navigate` of the custom WeekView class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, react-big-calendar

I am trying to have a custom week view as per https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/examples/demos/customView.js.

In that example, they have taken a custom number of days as 3. I want to have it *dynamic* (by keeping state variable). I am planning to change the state variable based on the screen size. (I have put the window width event listener to update that state variable)

Now the problem is how can I access that state variable inside the `navigate` and `title` static functions? Because they will be custom based on the no of days.

Answer (score 0):

If the custom view was a React function component, and your state value was defined in a wrapping context, you could use hooks, and use a custom context hook inside the custom week view component for access to the state value.